# adding the admin user to access the activemq queues

Tags: activemq-classic

I have setup an activemq and configured the queue with users. I have created one queue and two users namely `producer` and `consumer` with read write permissions appropriately. I am able to post message using `producer` and consume the message using `consumer`.

When I login to the admin page of activemq using `admin/admin` I am not able to view the messages inside the queue. How to add `admin` user to access the queue.

I have added the below configuration entry in the `activemq.xml`

```
     <plugins>
      <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
        <users>
            <authenticationUser username="producer" password="producer" groups="producers" />
            <authenticationUser username="consumer" password="consumer" groups="consumers" />
            <authenticationUser username="defaultUser"  password="defaultPassword" groups="admins" />
        </users>
      </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
      <authorizationPlugin>
        <map>
            <authorizationMap>
                <authorizationEntries>
                    <authorizationEntry queue="test.Queue" write="producers" read="consumers" admin="admins" />
                    <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="producers,consumers" write="producers,producers" admin="admins,producers,consumers"/>
                </authorizationEntries>
            </authorizationMap>
        </map>
      </authorizationPlugin>
    </plugins>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin user for the web console is in admins group ?
I think you need to add authenticationUser username="admin"  password="admin" groups="admins" />

Comment: Even after adding the above entry I am not able to access the queue.

Comment: Have you updated the credentials.properties with one admin user from the simpleAuthentificationPlugin ? You need to add the user "system" with pwd "manager" as admin ` <authenticationUser username="system" password="manager" groups="admins" /> & add this authorization for queue <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins"/> & for topics <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins"/>`